# use php to loop csv data and display subjects by topic and topic by category

Tags: php, loops, csv

[image: excel data]

This is var_dump($data); from the csv file

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(7) "Topic A" [2]=> string(8) "Alphabet" [3]=> string(12) "Category One" [4]=> string(3) "ONE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(7) "Topic B" [2]=> string(10) "Basketball" [3]=> string(12) "Category One" [4]=> string(3) "ONE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Food" [2]=> string(6) "Fruits" [3]=> string(12) "Category Two" [4]=> string(3) "TWO" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Food" [2]=> string(10) "Vegetables" [3]=> string(12) "Category Two" [4]=> string(3) "TWO" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "6" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Cars" [2]=> string(7) "Compact" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "7" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Cars" [2]=> string(11) "Convertible" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "8" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Cars" [2]=> string(5) "Sedan" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "9" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Cars" [2]=> string(3) "SUV" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Cars" [2]=> string(6) "Hybrid" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Cars" [2]=> string(5) "Wagon" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(17) "Topic Motorcycles" [2]=> string(7) "2-Wheel" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "15" [1]=> string(17) "Topic Motorcycles" [2]=> string(7) "3-Wheel" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "16" [1]=> string(17) "Topic Motorcycles" [2]=> string(7) "Sidecar" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "19" [1]=> string(12) "Topic Trucks" [2]=> string(7) "Compact" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(12) "Topic Trucks" [2]=> string(8) "Crew Cab" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "21" [1]=> string(12) "Topic Trucks" [2]=> string(8) "Long Bed" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(12) "Topic Trucks" [2]=> string(9) "Short Bed" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "23" [1]=> string(12) "Topic Trucks" [2]=> string(6) "Hybrid" [3]=> string(14) "Category Three" [4]=> string(5) "THREE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "32" [1]=> string(9) "Topic Art" [2]=> string(8) "Painting" [3]=> string(13) "Category Four" [4]=> string(4) "FOUR" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "33" [1]=> string(12) "Topic Design" [2]=> string(9) "Rendering" [3]=> string(13) "Category Four" [4]=> string(4) "FOUR" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "34" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Math" [2]=> string(7) "Algebra" [3]=> string(13) "Category Five" [4]=> string(4) "FIVE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "35" [1]=> string(10) "Topic Math" [2]=> string(7) "Physics" [3]=> string(13) "Category Five" [4]=> string(4) "FIVE" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "36" [1]=> string(13) "Topic Science" [2]=> string(7) "Physics" [3]=> string(13) "Category Five" [4]=> string(4) "FIVE" }
```

need to loop through the csv data and group by same category, then same topic.
I'm having trouble with nesting foreach loops and actually not sure that is the right method.

Here is my php

```
$src_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."\\include\\excel.csv";
    $row = 1;
    $count = 0;
                    
if (($src_file_handle = fopen($src_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
// testing
$category = [];
$topic = [];
$subject = [];
while (($data = fgetcsv($src_file_handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {     
$category[] = $data[3];
$topic[] = $data[1];
$subject[] = $data[2];
}
    
fclose($src_file_handle);
}
// testing
$arraySize = 24;
$i = 0;
while($i < $arraySize)
{
    echo "<div class=\"section\">";
    echo "<h4 class=\"title\">" .$category[$i]."</h4>";
    echo "<h5>" .$topic[$i]. "</h5>";
    echo "<p>" .$subject[$i]. "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
$i++;
} 
?>
```

which produces:
category

topic

subject

Category One

Topic A

Alphabet

Category One

Topic B

Basketball

Category Two

Topic Food

Fruits

Category Two

Topic Food

Vegetables

Category Three

Topic Cars

Compact

Category Three

Topic Cars

Convertible

Category Three

Topic Cars

Sedan

Category Three

Topic Cars

SUV

Category Three

Topic Cars

Hybrid

Category Three

Topic Cars

Wagon

Category Three

Topic Motorcycles

2-Wheel

Category Three

Topic Motorcycles

3-Wheel

Category Three

Topic Motorcycles

Sidecar

Category Three

Topic Trucks

Compact

Category Three

Topic Trucks

Crew Cab

Category Three

Topic Trucks

Long Bed

Category Three

Topic Trucks

Short Bed

Category Three

Topic Trucks

Hybrid

Category Four

Topic Art

Painting

Category Four

Topic Design

Rendering

Category Five

Topic Math

Algebra

Category Five

Topic Math

Physics

Category Five

Topic Science

Physics

Desired output using php would be:

**Category One**

```
Topic A
   Alphabet

Topic B
   Basketball
```

**Category Two**

```
Topic Food
   Fruits
   Vegetables
```

**Category Three**

```
Topic Cars
   Compact
   Convertible
   Sedan
   SUV
   Hybrid
   Wagon
Topic Motorcycles
   2-Wheel
   3-Wheel
   Sidecar
Topic Trucks
   Compact
   Crew Cab
   Long Bed
   Short Bed
   Hybrid
```

**Category Four**

```
Topic Art
   Painting
Topic Design
   Rendering
```

**Category Five**

```
Topic Math
   Physics
Topic Science
   Physics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$src_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\\include\\excel.csv";
$row = 1;
$count = 0;

if (($src_file_handle = fopen($src_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $current_category = '';
    $current_topic = '';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($src_file_handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($count == 0) 
            $count++;
        else {
            $skip_category = ($current_category != $data[3]) ? false : true;
            $skip_topic = ($current_topic != $data[1]) ? false : true;

            echo (!$skip_category) ? "<div class=\"section\">" : "";
            echo (!$skip_category) ? "<h4 class=\"title\">" . $data[3] . "</h4>" : "";
            echo (!$skip_topic) ? "<h5>&nbsp;" . $data[1] . "</h5>" : "";
            echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $data[2] . "</p>";
            echo (!$skip_category) ? "</div>" : "";

            $current_category = $data[3];
            $current_topic = $data[1];
        }
    }
    fclose($src_file_handle);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: That works fabulously! Thank you!

Comment: only a minor change added to skip the first, header row of the excel sheet.
just inside the while
if($count == 0){
            $count++;
        } 
 else {
...
$skip_category
...
         } // closes else
} // closes while
  fclose($src_file_handle);
} // closes if

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the answer

Comment: oh no need to edit it, I was just mentioning that I modified it slightly. I appreciate your solution, it really did the trick.